# How to access key-value tuples in forward/reverse order for Dict and SortedDict? - Julia

Tags: sorting, dictionary, julia, key-value

Given a dictionary:

```
> d = Dict{Int, Int}(1=>123, 2=>51, 4=>23)
Dict{Int64,Int64} with 3 entries:
  4 => 23
  2 => 51
  1 => 123
```

I could access a dictionary's value by its key, e.g.:

```
> d[4]
23
```

Or I could looped through the key-value pairs as such:

```
> for i in d
         println(i)
       end
4=>23
2=>51
1=>123
```

I've tried accessing the key as the first element of the list or even `i.key`, but it doesn't seem to be the right syntax:

```
julia> for i in d
         println(i.key)
       end
ERROR: type Pair has no field key
 in macro expansion; at ./REPL[22]:2 [inlined]
 in anonymous at ./<missing>:?

julia> for i in d
         println(i[0])
       end
ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 4=>23
  at index [0]
 in getindex(::Pair{Int64,Int64}, ::Int64) at ./operators.jl:609
 in macro expansion; at ./REPL[23]:2 [inlined]
 in anonymous at ./<missing>:?
```

And then I remembered that Julia is not 0th index, so it should be:

```
> for i in d
         println(i[1], ' ', i[2])
       end
4 23
2 51
1 123

> for i in d
         println(i[1], ' ', i[2])
       end
4 23
2 51
1 123
```

In this case **is the `BoundsError` somewhat like the Python's `IndexError` when an index of the list isn't found?**

The other part of the question is on `SortedDict`, **how do I access the last Nth element in the `SortedDict`?**

I've tried using the index syntax and I retrieved the value but not the tuple of `(key,value)`.

```
julia> import DataStructures: SortedDict

julia> sd = SortedDict(d)
DataStructures.SortedDict{Int64,Int64,Base.Order.ForwardOrdering} with 3 entries:
  1 => 123
  2 => 51
  4 => 23

julia> sd[end]
23
```

**Also, how can I sort the dictionary based on the value?**

And, lastly, **how to reverse the sorted dict?**

I've tried using `Base.Order.ReverseOrding` but it threw a `MethodError`:

```
julia> sd = SortedDict{Base.Order.ReverseOrdering}(d)
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Dict{Int64,Int64} to an object of type DataStructures.SortedDict{Base.Order.ReverseOrdering,D,Ord<:Base.Order.Ordering}
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor DataStructures.SortedDict{Base.Order.ReverseOrdering,D,Ord<:Base.Order.Ordering}(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
 in DataStructures.SortedDict{Base.Order.ReverseOrdering,D,Ord<:Base.Order.Ordering}(::Dict{Int64,Int64}) at ./sysimg.jl:53
```

Comment: this question is a lot to chew on. in the future, consider splitting it into two questions...

Comment: Please ask each question separately. Also, it is not helpful to include the attempt with indexing pairs by `0`. If you wish to ask about `BoundsError`, that can also be done separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not a Python user, but the documentation for [IndexError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError) looks similar to the documentation for [BoundsError](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/base/?highlight=boundserror#Base.BoundsError). Note that you can always query current Julia documentation with `?`, e.g.

```
?BoundsError
```

You can sort dictionary keys and values:

```
d = Dict{Int,Int}(1 => 2, 3 => 4)
k = sort(collect(keys(d)) ### collect() forms an array that you can sort
v = sort(collect(values(d))
```

but I cannot see why you would want to sort by value. Why not simply use the values as keys?

You can loop through keys or values easily:

```
for k in keys(d)  ### or "for v in values(d)..."
    println(k)
end
```

When using `SortedDict`, make sure that such an ordering makes sense. In this toy example the keys of `d` are integers, and they have a logical order with `isless` and `isequal`; see documentation [here](http://datastructuresjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sorted_containers.html#ordering-of-keys).

You can obtain the last entry of a `SortedDict` with `last`:

```
using DataStructures
D = SortedDict(d)
last(D) ### 3=>4
```

Use the `Reverse` module to flip the order:

```
using Reverse
D2 = SortedDict(d, Reverse)
```

Comment: is there a `lastsecond()` for SortedDict ? or `lastn(D, n)` where `n` is the last nth item?

Comment: nope. sounds like something that you could contribute to Julia ;-)